# Import-module not finding container installed modules

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, powershell-core

In Jenkins when I run a pipeline and attempt to use the modules in the container I'm getting modules not found as below:

I'm using a "Powershell" build step.

When I run the container interactively I'm able to see the modules as below (#3):

## 1

```
[Tatux.Utils] $ pwsh -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File /tmp/jenkins1449086927549124636.ps1
################################
Running on node 745612521e5a
Build: jenkins-Powershell-Tatux.Utils-16
################################


    Directory: /opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ---------
Manifest   1.2.5                 Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive        Desk     
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           Core     
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     Core     
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       Core     
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        Core     
Script     1.4.6                 PackageManagement                   Desk     
Script     2.2.3                 PowerShellGet                       Desk     
Script     2.0.5                 PSDesiredStateConfiguration         Core     
Script     2.0.0                 PSReadLine                          Desk     
Binary     2.0.3                 ThreadJob                           Desk     
[91mImport-Module: [0m/tmp/jenkins1449086927549124636.ps1:9
[96mLine |
[96m   9 | [0m [96mImport-Module Pester, PSScriptAnalyzer[0m
[96m     | [91m ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[91m[96m     | [91mThe specified module 'Pester' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
[0m
Build step 'PowerShell' marked build as failure
Recording NUnit tests results
FATAL: No NUnit test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is my *dockerfile*:

## 2

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:7.0.0-ubuntu-18.04

MAINTAINER "Nigel Tatschner"

# Set up required repos

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -qy full-upgrade && \
    apt-get install -qy git && \
# Install a basic SSH server
    apt-get install -qy openssh-server && \
    sed -i 's|session    required     pam_loginuid.so|session    optional     pam_login$
    mkdir -p /var/run/sshd && \
# Install JDK 8 (latest stable edition at 2019-04-01)
    apt-get install -qy openjdk-8-jdk && \
# Cleanup old packages
    apt-get -qy autoremove && \
# Add user jenkins to the image
    adduser --quiet jenkins && \
# Set password for the jenkins user (you may want to alter this).
    echo "####:####" | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/#####/.m2

RUN mkdir /home/jenkins/.ssh/ \
    && chown -R ####:####/home/####/.m2/ \
    && chown -R ####:#### /home/####/.ssh/

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

RUN pwsh -command "install-Module -Name Pester, PSScriptAnalyzer -force"
# Standard SSH port
EXPOSE 22

CMD [ "pwsh" ]
```

The output from the interactive tty session:

## 3

[image: Interactive tty session with container using image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this before calling `Import-Module`:

```bsh
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Refresh | Out-Null
```

Alternatively, you may be able to import Pester using its absolute path:

```bsh
Import-Module /root/.local/share/powershell/Modules/Pester
```